# Are all files viewable to the public?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am hosting my Discord bot using Heroku but I didn't know if the files I upload using Heroku Git (CLI) keeps them locked so where no one can view the token and connect to my bot. If they are not private, how would I go and make the token private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku doesn't publish your source code, so if you only use the keys in your server-side code you are probably okay.

But your keys probably shouldn't be hard-coded into your application anyway. A better practice is to pull them in from [the environment](https://12factor.net/config). This is [directly supported by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: Used heroku with a discord but, no errors with token and running like normal. Thank you for informing me.